# Add multiple views into acitivity one below other

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/city_detail_activity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shopping_movies"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shopping_name"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TextView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/movies"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is create multiple instances of my layout and add it one by one inside my activity.

My activity code is like that:

```
for (int i =0; i < shoppings.size(); i++)
{
    LinearLayout shopping_movies = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(CityActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.shopping_movies, null);
    TextView shopping_name = (TextView) shopping_movies.findViewById(R.id.shopping_name);
    shopping_name.setText(shopp.name);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutt.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    addContentView(shopping_movies, params);
}
```

The problem is that each layout is added at position 0. One in front other and not below. I just tried `addRule(LinearLayout.BELOW, lastId)` but does not work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem adding a empty LinearLayout in my activity.

MyActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/city_detail_activity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/shoppings"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my java code:

```
for (int i =0; i < shoppings.size(); i++)
{
    LinearLayout shopping_movies = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(CityDetailActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.shopping_movies, null);
    ((TextView) shopping_movies.findViewById(R.id.shopping_name)).setText(shopp.name);

    LinearLayout shoppingsViewGroup = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.shoppings);

    shoppingsViewGroup.addView(shopping_movies);
}
```

Comment: It's not worth nesting two layouts, you can safely remove the @id/shoppings layout and add your views into @id/city_detail_activity layout.

Comment: @Egor If I do that all my views are added one above the other.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` instead of `RelativeLayout` as the container for your views, as `orientation` doesn't have any effect in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem continues, each layout.xml is added in front previous layout.